# tensorflow image classifier with marker positions

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

Using a tensorflow image classifier would it be possible to return the marker positions of the items matched. [image]

For example the shoe in the picture using tensorflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to have what you want using a classical image classification model. What you need is a [segmentation](https://github.com/mrgloom/awesome-semantic-segmentation) network (your training data must be appropriately changed). However, theoretically, it is possible to loosely localize an object using classification techniques. See [this](https://leon.bottou.org/publications/pdf/cvpr-2015.pdf)